# Link error when using clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR extension function

Tags: c++, interop, opencl, lnk2019

I recently began incorporating OpenCL into my OpenGL application that renders a basic particle system, the basic interoperation–without events–between the two works fine. However, having tried to use the `clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR` function in order to improve performance instead of having to call `glFinish` and `clFinish`, I am unable to get the running program as the program complains with the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR
```

I have tried to use both of the provided functions used to obtain extension-function pointers (`clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform`, `clGetExtensionFunctionAddress`) but for reasons I cant fathom, I am not able to get it to work.

Sample code:

```
#include <CL/cl_gl_ext.h>

typedef cl_event (*PFNCLCREATEEVENTFROMGLSYNCKHR) (cl_context context, cl_GLsync sync, cl_int *errcode_ret);

PFNCLCREATEEVENTFROMGLSYNCKHR clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR = (PFNCLCREATEEVENTFROMGLSYNCKHR)clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(opencl::target::inst()->platform(), "clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR");

GLsync sync = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);

cl_event gl_event = clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR(opencl::contexts["GL_CL_context"]->_get(), sync, NULL );
```

Would anyone kindly assist me in understanding as to where it is I am going wrong?

For those interested:

```
Name:                        GeForce GT 740M
Vendor:                  NVIDIA Corporation
Device OpenCL C version:             OpenCL C 1.1 
Driver version:              327.23
Profile:                     FULL_PROFILE
Version:                     OpenCL 1.1 CUDA
Extensions:                  cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options 
cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll  cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics 
cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64
```

**Update**
The above code still does not work if I use a device that supports the cl_khr_gl_event extension

Comment: What happens if you change the name of your variable `clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR` to something else? Is it the variable or something else that is causing the error, is what I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: I recieve an error relating to an undefined value

Comment: ...when i try to perform a function call

Answer (score 0):

Your device does not support `cl_khr_gl_event` extension. That extension is needed to use the `clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR` method. As stated [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/gl_event.html). Typically all the methods that are part of an extension end/start have KHR/NV/AMD in their name.

Another problem with your code, is that you have not enabled the extension anyway, with you have to do by defining the following:

```
#include <CL/cl_gl_ext.h>
```

Comment: Apollogies that that was not included in the sample code but is in the actual code itself.
Interesting point, I have two GPUs one without the extension as you have highlighted and another that does. However the same occurs if I use the device with the extension.
Could my problem now be the way in which the above code has been written?

Comment: It may be the library you are linking does not have the method. Are you linking with nVIDIA? Do you have another library to link with?

Comment: After messing around with it (using the same code) it is now giving me the following error:

Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly  saved across a function call.  This is usually a   result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

Comment: For crash safety, you should check if you're getting a non-NULL result from clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform.

Comment: From the spec: "A return value of NULL indicates that the specified function does not exist for the implementation or platform is not a valid platform. A non-NULL return value for clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform does not guarantee that an extension function is actually supported by the platform. The application must also make a corresponding query using clGetPlatformInfo (platform, CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS, ... ) or clGetDeviceInfo (device,CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, ... ) to determine if an extension is supported by the OpenCL implementation."